# Waitr and Jira integration not producing desired output

Tags: ruby

I wrote a Ruby script to check if the layer found in DOM in Firebug for the page www.jira.com is matching with the hash values declared in my script. Below is the Ruby script I have written:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)

browser.goto('https://jira.com')

JIRA_DATA_LAYER = {
    'jira' => {
               'event'     => ['gtm.js', 'gtm.load'],
               'gtm.start' => '1468949036556',
              }
}

def get_jira_data_layer(get_data_layer)
    result = []

    get_data_layer.each do |data_layer|
        data_layer.each do |data_layer_key, data_layer_value|
            result << {"#{data_layer_key}" => data_layer_value}
        end
    end

    return result
end

def compare_jira_data_layer(layer, jira_name)
    message = []
    index = 0

    JIRA_DATA_LAYER[jira_name].each do |jira_key, jira_value|
        if layer.include?({jira_key => jira_value})
            result = 'matches - PASS'
        else
            result = 'matches - FAIL'
        end

        index += 1
        message.push("'#{jira_key} => #{jira_value}' #{result}")
    end

    return message.join("\n")
end

data_layer = browser.execute_script("return dataLayer")
get_data_layer = get_jira_data_layer(data_layer)
compare_data_layer = compare_jira_data_layer(get_data_layer, "jira")
puts compare_data_layer
```

I am getting the following output:

```
'event => ["gtm.js", "gtm.load"]' matches - FAIL
'gtm.start => 1468949036556' matches - FAIL
```

I want the following to be achieved:

```
'event => gtm.js' matches - FAIL
'gtm.start => 1468949036556' matches - FAIL
```

Comment: Remember "doesn't work" is about as meaningless a description as you can give.

Comment: @tadman Oh.Thanks and sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the value for `event` key in JIRA_DATA_LAYER, but I guess it has to be that way.

Try to expand `if` sentence when checking key for this hash and use `is_a?` method to check whether value for particular key is array or not. If so, loop through `each` member of this array.

Comment: I really thank you for the suggestion you gave but it would really be of great help if you can give me the code